# Syntax error while calling subroutine in fortran

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fortran

I am calling one subroutine and its showing me syntax error. I am using intel visual fortran with Visual studio. But before this I was running with compaq vidual fortran and it was running successfully. This is the line of code where the syntax error is:

```
call XLIMEX(n,Fcn,Jacobian,t_Begin,t_End,y,ys,rTol,aTol,h,Iopt, &
      Ropt,IPos,IFail)
```

I started from column 7 and end before column 77, how can I solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: You must show a complete piece of code and the compilation command you run including the file name and the full error message you get. Also learn how to format your question to be more readable.

Comment: Awesome, Its running now. It was a small error. Next time I will try to put question more readable.

Comment: It is more important to supply all the necessary information. The readability comes only after that. You should still add the info to make the question more complete for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you mention the 7th column and the 70th column I suppose you use the fixed form source.

In fixed form you must continue using `&` (or other character) in the fifth column on the new line, not by `&` at the first line. The way you used is for the free form sources.

Comment: When refactoring from fixed to free form input, I put a `&` in column 73 of each line that is continued and a `&` in column 6 of each line that continues. Fixed format parsers are typically set to ignore anything past column 73, and free format parsers treat the trailing/leading ampersand pair as a single continuation character. This is especially helpful when refactoring `include` files which may be pulled into either free or fixed format source files.

Comment: True, I know this trick, I even mentioned this several times on StackOverflow ;) It is described on fortranwiki as an intersection form. The disadvantage is that some compilers couldbstill try to interpret it.